# Precompile nunjucks templates using Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, webpack-4, nunjucks

Moving from Gulp to Webpack (it's a Backbone.js app). I need to precompile all the **`*.html`** files (`nunjucks` templates) & concat into a single `js` file (e.g. template.min.js).

How can I do that using `webpack.config.js`?

Project structure:

```js
js/
  apps/
    app.js

  views/
    v1.js  // from here using templates, not by require
    v2.js

templates/
  t1.html  // these are nunjucks files
  t2.html  

webpack.config.js
```

---

How using Nunjucks templates into JS codes (Backbone.js)?

```js
module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({

  t1Tpl: 't1.html', // template file path into templates/ directory

  el: 'body',
  ...
  ...
  render() {
    $('body').html(global.nunjucksEnv.render(this.t1Tpl));
  }
  ...
  ...
});
```

this was the previous `gulp.task` to precompile & concat the file:

```js
const nunjucks = require('gulp-nunjucks');
...
...
gulp.task('templates', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.templates.files) // get all the templates/**/*.html files
   .pipe(nunjucks())                    // precompile
   .pipe(concat('templates.min.js'))    // concat into a single templates.min.js file
});
```

**I want to do the exact task using Webpack Rules/Plugins configs.**

Comment: From the top of my head I don't know whether there is a way to accomplish this (there surely is), but even if there is one, it wouldn't be "idiomatic webpack". What speaks against loading the template via the [nunjucks-loader](https://github.com/at0g/nunjucks-loader) and require instead of stating the filename in the View (`t1Tpl: require('nunjucks!./views/t1.html')`)? It would even add the benefit of compile time errors if the template file name has a typo in the backbone view.

Comment: ok, then I've to do lots of change in every view file (I've thousands of view files & every file has multiple templates). It would be great if I can do this without changing in view files!

Comment: Couldn't this be achieved mostly by search/replace? Replace `Tpl: '` by `Tpl: require('...`

Comment: I need precompiled `*.js` file. If I do `require('...')`, it's not working with `global.nunjucksEnv.render(this.t1Tpl)` command.

Comment: Yes, the `global.nunjucksEnv.render` has to be slightly adjusted. It just has to call `.render(params)` on the passed parameter `this.t1Tpl` as described in tje docs of nunjuck-loader: `var tpl = require('./views/page.njk');
var html = tpl.render({ message: 'Foo that!' });`